# How select a percent of population.

Tags: combinations, percentages

I have a cars process function Im trying to optimize, right now isn't fast enough to process all the data, so I want to reduce the % of input.

I **cant** filter using random rows, because cars send continuos data and I need track the changes for each car (how much each car move in time). So I choose filter based in `car_id`

Select a size below 50% is easy, I can use the remainder of division to  filter some %:

```
WHERE car_id % 2 = 0  -- select 50% of rows
WHERE car_id % 3 = 0  --        33%
WHERE car_id % 4 = 0  --        25%
```

I can calculate `1/n` to get the pecentage selected.

My function already can manage 50% very efficent so I want increase the flow of data. But not sure how  measure the limit in the other direction.

Using excel and filling cell with `1 .. 100` I was able to know:

```
WHERE car_id % 2 = 0 
   OR car_id % 3 = 0  -- Select 66%

WHERE car_id % 2 = 0 
   OR car_id % 3 = 0
   OR car_id % 4 = 0  -- Also Select 66% (now I know need combine prime numbers)

WHERE car_id % 2 = 0 
   OR car_id % 3 = 0
   OR car_id % 5 = 0  -- Select 74%
```

But dont know what formula can give me that result.

And how can I calculate a combination allow me to select something specific like `~70%`

Comment: Why not just order the cars and determine if the car_id is less than 70% of the number of cars.

Comment: @KitterCatter because I dont know the number of cars before hand, I just in the other end receiving the information. I just assume the car_id has a normal distribution.

Comment: Could you just assign a random number between 0 and 1 then check if it is less than .7 and keep it if it is?

Comment: @KitterCatter I guess I could keep a table and only insert 7 and discard the next 3, and if already on the table selected. But that requiere some work. I was just trying to think in a mathematic solution. And try to understand why `%2 or %3` select `66%`

Comment: What you described is extremely straightforward and requires basically no real work on your part other than if (x mod 10 in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ) then keep.

For your latter question just think of what could satisfy %2 and %3 simultaneously. You should be led to consider lcm(2,3) = 6, of which 2 satisfy the latter, 3 satisfy the former, 1 of which satisfies both, 2+3-1=4. 4/6=2/3~66%

Comment: @KitterCatter Ohh I like `(x mod 10) in 1234567`  very easy.

Comment: @KitterCatter The second part isnt clear. How is the calculation for `(%2, %3, %5 = 74%)` ?

Comment: For the former consideration it turns out (0 mod 2) or (1 mod 5) or (2 mod 5) will give you an answer.

For the latter: 2*3*5=30:
15 for 2;
10 for 3;
  6 for 5;
 5 overlap for 2 and 3 (30/(2*3));
 3 overlap for 2 and 5;
 2 overlap for 3 and 5;
 1 overlap for all 3;
15+10+6-5-3-2+1=22/30 = 11/15 ~ .73

Comment: Mod[#, 2] == 0 || Mod[#, 5] == 0 || Mod[#, 10] == 1 works, it's got the same pattern you were using with the exception of Mod 10 being 1 instead of 0.